# How to convert 3 colum in an excel matrix?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, database

I have many data set on 3 column as the tab above

[image: tab above]

and I would like to convert to a

[image: matrix]

like the one in the picture.

Is there a function that do this in MS-excel 2007?

I think I need to create a pivot table, but when I set ITEM for the row and date on the column it create a matrix with "1" value and not the "SOLD column" value

Comment: yes, there is, it's called pivot table. You can find several tutorials on it on-line.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I think I made a mistake with pivot table, I update the question

Comment: @MátéJuhász solved: you have to set what value to view in the matrix. My error was to set the default value (count) instead of **sum**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the setup of the table below. It's from Excel 2013, so it looks different, but the idea is the same.

[image]